# c++ how to create a function, that prints on terminal as well as file

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I want to create a function, that prints output according to its parameter.
Like if I pass a ofstream pointer it should print the output to the respective file, whereas if i pass cout  or something, that makes it print to the terminal.

Thanks :)

Comment: nope.
NO homework
Actually I used function overloading to do this, then I thought to do it the other way.
so posted here.

Comment: Just curious. Sounded like a possible assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void display(std::ostream& stream)
{
    stream << "Hello, World!";
}

...

display(cout);

std::ofstream fout("test.txt");
display(fout);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename CharT, typename TraitsT>
void print(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& os)
{
    // write to os
}
```

This will allow to write to any stream (narrow or wide, allowing custom traits).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream &output_something(std::ostream &out_stream, const T &value) {
    return out_stream << value;
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
ofstream out_file("some_file");
output_something(out_file, "bleh");  // prints to "some_file"
output_something(std::cout, "bleh"); // prints to stdout
```